# Multiple next-hops for a destination

Tags: ubuntu, routing, ipv4

I want to add a primary next-hop for a destination and then a secondary next-hope for the same destination, in case the first one fails. How can i do that? i couldn't find a straight answer on the Internet.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: How do you define fails?  Are you expecting the to only detect if the next hop fails or are you expecting to find some method to know that the link is broken upstream?

Answer (score 1):

Look up "metrics".

These are used to calculate the "cost" of a route, the lowest being the best, but as i understand it they aren't fully used with static routing, so you'll need a routing protocol to take advantage of it (rip, ospf, etc).

> The last argument on the command line is the routing metric. The metric argument is not used when routes are deleted, but some older systems require it when a route is added; for Solaris 8, the metric is optional. Systems that require a metric value for the route command use it only to decide if this is a route through a directly attached interface or a route through an external gateway. If the metric is 0, the route is installed as a route through a local interface, and the G flag, which we saw in the netstat -i display, is not set. If the metric value is greater than 0, the route is installed with the G flag set, and the gateway address is assumed to be the address of an external gateway. Static routing makes no real use of the metric. Dynamic routing is required to make real use of varying metric values.

Info from [this guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/tcp/ch07_03.htm)